# How can i compare value staffNo of different class and how do i know if a list exists in java

Tags: java, list, class, object

I have three different staff class. first is dentist class, second is nurse class, third is receptionist class and I have aa staff class which is inheriting other classes

Sample code about dentist class:

```
public class Dentist extends Staff {
private final int GDCRegNo = randInt(1000000, 9999999);

private List<Patient> patients;
private List<Dentist> dentists;

public Dentist(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    List<Dentist> dentists;
    
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
}
```

and Sample code about staff class:

```
public class Staff {

protected int staffNo = randInt(1000,9999);
protected String name;

private int getStaffNo() {
    return this.staffNo;
}

private String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    List<Dentist> dentists;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}

}
```

I want to set all different staffNo of object of class(staffNo of dentist class, nurse class and receptionist class) unique with lists and
I want to set all GDCRegNo of dentist object unique with lists

How can I do that?

I thought If I can get all number of class and compare them I can solve it but how?

Comment: Why do you use Random numbers? Can you just use sequential numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one static field in `Staff` class to help you generate new unique id when new object instantiate

```java
public class Staff {

   // last used id when instantiate new object
   protected static int lastId = 0;

   protected int staffNo;
   protected String name;
   
   public Staff() {
      this.staffNo = lastId;
      // increment lastId, so next instance will have different id
      lastId++; 
   }
}
```

In the subclass just call super constructor:

```java
public class Dentist extends Staff {
    
    public Dentist(String name) {
       super();
       this.name = name;
    }
}
```